# Issue with displaying Firestore collection in RecylcerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display a Firestore collection in a `RecylcerView` but cannot get it to display here is the code.

ViewCars.java:

```
    public class ViewCars extends AppCompatActivity {
        private RecyclerView mCarList;
        private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
        private List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        private CarListAdapter carListAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cars);
            carListAdapter = new CarListAdapter(carsList);
            mCarList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
            mCarList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mCarList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mCarList.setAdapter(carListAdapter);
            firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Cars").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    for(DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                        if(doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                            Car car = doc.getDocument().toObject(Car.class);
                            carsList.add(car);
                            carListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.d("Car List", Integer.toString(carsList.size()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

CarListAdapter:

public class ViewCars extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mCarList;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    private CarListAdapter carListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cars);
        carListAdapter = new CarListAdapter(carsList);
        mCarList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
        mCarList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mCarList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mCarList.setAdapter(carListAdapter);
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Cars").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                for(DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                    if(doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                        Car car = doc.getDocument().toObject(Car.class);
                        carsList.add(car);
                        carListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Log.d("Car List", Integer.toString(carsList.size()));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Car.java:

```
public class Car {
    private String id;
    private String numPlate;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String year;
    private String price;

    public Car(){

    }

    public Car(String id, String numPlate, String make, String model, String year, String price) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setNumPlate(numPlate);
        this.setMake(make);
        this.setModel(model);
        this.setYear(year);
        this.setPrice(price);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumPlate() {
        return numPlate;
    }

    public void setNumPlate(String numPlate) {
        this.numPlate = numPlate;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Originally I was getting an error saying the carList array was null and I fixed that and now nothing happens when i load up the activity the only thing coming up that i think might be affecting it is this in the debugger.

[[image: Debug warning[1]]

Other than this there is no clear issue in my eyes. Any assistance you could offer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get those errors because in your model class your fields are declared using lower case letters and in your database exist with the first letter capital. That's why you get:

```
No setter/field for Year on...
```

See, `Year` has first letter `Y` capital. In order to solve this, you have 2 solutions. First one would be to delete the actual data and add fresh one, so the fields in your model class to be the same as in the database or to use annotations, by adding in front of every field the following annotation:

```
@PropertyName("Year")
private String year
```